# Turn off TalkBack/double tap on Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1

Tags: samsung, talk-back

On the Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1, after downloading the latest OS, some settings got changed and the TalkBack comes on. However, I cannot find a TalkBack accessibility item to turn off.

What's the workaround to shut this off/remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The TalkBack feature is now called "Voice Assistant" and accessible through Settings > Accessibility > Voice Assistant. From there, you can turn it off.